# Assigning variable with generic type after narrowing with typeof operator

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why I can't assign string value to variable with generic type after narrowing this generic to string type?

```
function a<T extends unknown> (arg: T) {
    if (typeof arg === 'string') {
        const b: T = ''
        // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        // 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'
    }
}
```

Can anyone describe the problem?

Comment: T can be a literal string like e.g. you can do `a<'mystring'|'myotherstring'>('mystring')` but then `''` is not `T`. The `typeof` check can only tell you something is a string, you'd need a stricter type guard for more specific strings

Comment: But why I can clearly say that `b: string = 'dsa'` and it's work. But here it doesn't work

Comment: You are saying `const b: T = ''` and `T` may not be any string but a specific string or union of strings

Comment: The caller gets to choose `T`, not the implementer.  And there are string literal types more specific than `string`.  If the caller calls `a("hello")` then `T` is the literal string type `"hello"` and `""` is not assignable to `T`.  Does this make sense or are you still confused?